# Bottle - Is it possible to retrieve URL without parameters?

Tags: python, bottle

I have an URL of the form:

```
http://www.foo.com/bar?arg1=x&arg2=y
```

If I do:

```
request.url
```

I get:

```
http://www.foo.com/bar?arg1=x&arg2=y
```

Is it possible to get just `http://www.foo.com/bar`?

Comment: You can always `urllib.parse.urlparse` the URL and then `urlunparse` it without the query parameters.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if in the `request` object might be something more straightforward. Otherwise it is a good workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like `request.urlparts.path` might be a way to do it.

Full documentation [here](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.BaseRequest).

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

There is a way to do this via requests library

```
r.json()['headers']['Host']
```

I personally find the split function better.

---

You can use `split` function with `?` as the delimiter to do this.

```
url = request.url.split("?")[0]
```

I'm not sure if this is the most effective/correct method though.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if in the `request` object might be something more straightforward. Otherwise it is a good workaround.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to remove the parameters to get base url do

> url = url.split('?',1)[0]

this will split the url at the '?' and then give you base url

or even

> url = url[:url.find('?')]

you can also use urlparse this is explained in the python docs at: https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html